# LibGDX: Create and dispose ShapeRenderer in render method?

Tags: java, libgdx

I'm using a `ShapeRenderer` object to create a color gradient in my game (`Screen` class). The allocated memory used to grow permanently until I started to dispose my `ShapeRenderer` object after every call. How can I reuse my color gradient? Is there a way to paint the gradient into a texture (only once for reuse in the render method)?

```
public void render(float deltaTime) {
    camera.update();
    batch.setProjectionMatrix(camera.combined);

    ShapeRenderer shapeRenderer = new ShapeRenderer();
    shapeRenderer.setProjectionMatrix(camera.combined);
    shapeRenderer.begin(ShapeRenderer.ShapeType.Filled);
    shapeRenderer.rect(0, 0, screenWidth, screenHeight, topColor, topColor, bottomColor, bottomColor);
    shapeRenderer.end();
    shapeRenderer.dispose();

    batch.begin();
    ...
    batch.end();
}
```

Comment: I'd not render this on the fly but supply premade images instead. However, if you want to keep doing that for some reason, you could use a [`Framebuffer`](http://libgdx.badlogicgames.com/nightlies/docs/api/com/badlogic/gdx/graphics/glutils/FrameBuffer.html) to render it to a texture for reuse.

Comment: As a small improvement I have made shapeRenderer a class variable, so I don't need to dispose it anymore (in the `render` method). Using `Framebuffer` sounds good (although I still don't know how to do this). I would prefer to create the gradients on the fly because I need many different ones. This should also have the advantage that the gradients look smoother even on super high dpi devices (compared to scaled Textures).

Comment: What do you think about making color gradient images of 1px width and different heights and then scaling them to screen width? Would that be over-optimization?

Comment: No, that's a perfectly valid approach. Although you don't even need to make different heights. Stretching them along the gradient also works.

Answer (score 3):

Although it seems you have solved your problem, here is just a little note for you and anyone stumbling across this post with a similar question.

Do not instantiate new Objects (of any type) during every run through a loop, at all costs. The reason you were experiencing slow-down is because of exactly this. Every time you instantiate a new object and then stop using it, the JVM's Garbage Collector needs to get rid of that Object. You should always try to reuse objects. This is why [pools](http://libgdx.badlogicgames.com/nightlies/docs/api/com/badlogic/gdx/utils/Pool.html) and [memory management](https://github.com/libgdx/libgdx/wiki/Memory-management) in general (these links are for LibGdx specificially) are so important.

Your notion to make a field for the ShapeRenderer was a good one, just don't forget to `dispose()` it in your game's `dispose()` method.